# iOS Share Activity - Add Custom Actions

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

See the image attached.

What are the APIs needed to add a share action here that shows up across the system.

How did Pinterest add theirs here? And it shows up for almost everything you share.

I've been looking around and the only thing that looked like maybe is `UIActivity`. But when I implemented it doesn't show up across other apps.

I was also lookin through app shortcut and app intent documentation but I can't find exactly how Pinterest is providing this action here.

[image: Custom Actions?]

Comment: By the way, when I look in the shortcuts app the Pinterest app doesn't even have a shortcut available. How did they get this there? lololol

Comment: See [App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/). You want either an Activity or Share extension.

Comment: Not a share extension, those have the app icons. I mean in the list of actions. And UIActivity only shows up in my app. How would you add to this list when other apps use a share activity?

Comment: But what about an Activity Extension? Did you look at the documentation I linked?

Comment: @HangarRash nice! I kinda glossed over that page because it looks like just a marketing page. But looking into the Activity extension I think this is what I need.